# Precompiling templates in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I am creating a Ember project with a Node backend and would like to have my templates as separate files instead of them being inline in the index.html file.  I have read many articles explaining this, but I still can't wrap my head around the full process and what the index.html file, etc. will look like when it is all done.  Is Grunt the most efficient to do something like this?  Here is what my grunt file looks like.

Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ember-templates');
grunt.registerTask('build', ['emberTemplates', 'concat', 'uglify']); //pass the compiled templates into your concat and uglify tasks. Don't worry, they don't care if they are mushed altogether


// with the following task in the Grunt.config
emberTemplates: {
    compileComponents: {
        options: {
            templateBasePath: /templates\//
        },
        files: {
            'build/precompile/components.js': 'templates/components/*.hbs'
        }
    },
    compileRoutes: {
        options: {
            templateBasePath: /templates\/routes\//
        },
        files: {
            'build/precompile/routes.js': ['templates/routes/*.hbs', 'templates/routes/**/*.hbs']
        }
    },
    compilePartials: {
        options: {
            templateBasePath: /templates\/partials\//
        },
        files: {
            'build/precompile/partials.js': 'templates/partials/*.hbs'
        }
    },
    compileSubstates: {
        options: {
            templateBasePath: /templates\/substates\//
        },
        files: {
            'build/precompile/substates.js': 'templates/substates/*.hbs'
        }
    },
    compileViews: {
        options: {
            templateBasePath: /templates\/views\//
        },
        files: {
            'build/precompile/views.js': 'templates/views/*.hbs'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The most efficient way to do this is by using the [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/)

Comment: Is there a specific part of that doc you could point me to that talks about this specifically? @Kitler

Comment: You will need to change your ember app into an ember-cli app, once you do that you can just run `ember build --environment=production` and it will handle everything for you and store the files in `dist/`

Comment: Oh really?  That's awesome.  Should I just delete everything related to grunt then?  Also, do I have to add anything to my index.html file? @Kitler

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that, for instance you will have to use ES6 modules, you will have to follow a project structure, install ember-cli and run `ember new testApp` and check out what gets generated, there is some learning to do here but it is much more organised and way more maintainable than the old global ember apps

Comment: This app actually is already an ember-cli app.  What should I do not that that is out of the way? @Kitler

Comment: Just run `ember build --environment=production` the files will be in `dist/`

Comment: Okay so I just did that and files were added to the dist/ folder but when I run my server, I still get a blank screen.  Any thoughts? @Kitler

Comment: Is the project public? If so can you share the repo?

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://github.com/EmmonsVentures/casteva @Kitler

Comment: You don't have any routes defined in `router.coffee`

Comment: Shouldn't it still display the root url just on the first page? @Kitler

Comment: I m not entirely sure how `ember-cli-emblem` works, I will have to give this a shot after work :/

Comment: Okay thank you! @Kitler

Comment: @NickEmmons you're using the Ember CLI already, you don't have to do anything with the templates. The CLI will do all of it for you.  If you install the `ember-cli-emblem` package, you can just use `.embl` extensions for your template files instead of `.hbs` and it should work for you.

Comment: Oh okay thanks Alex! @alexlafroscia